# How can I multiply different values considering all posible combination in a matrix in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, nested-loops

I have the values from multiple Array in a Matrix n x m. I want to get all possible combinations from the Matrix. Please see example bellow.

[Input and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdDEh.png)

Thank you.

Comment: is it an option for you to work on Python? I think it would be much easier for you to work with your array multiplication problem

Comment: @BrenoTeodoro inefficient code has no language barriers...

Comment: Since the code is working but simply inefficient, consider asking on [codereview.se] instead - you'll get much deeper & broader feedback on all aspects of the code than here on SO, which is usually more focused on specific issues.

Comment: Why do you have so many arrays? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you can rearrange your data table a little bit you should be able to capture all the stress data in a single two-dim array. That way you are a good step closer to a parametric solution with n columns.

Comment: Hello. First of all thank you for your answers. Yes Breno Teodoro, it would be better with Python and it is an Option as my results are in a txt file, but I do not have that much Knowledge.

Zac. I have something like 10 tables with 1000 rows. on each row I have a value for x and a value for y (positive and negative values). I have to get the maximum X by adding all the x values from the 10 tables (x1_1+x2_1+x3_1+x4_1...+x10_1(one combination); the next one  x1_1+x2_1+x3_1+x4_1...+x10_2 (and so on), and for the y in the same maner, with X and Y you get maximum shear.

Comment: Hello cars10m, I also thought of that but as I said in the previous comment I have to get all possible combinations between these values, I do not know how to move on each colum of the Matrix one value bellow.
11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25
31 32 33 34 35
41 42 43 44 45
 
The first combination
X=11+12+13+14+15
The seconde combination
X=11+12+13+14+25
I haven't yet manage to find a logic to avoid the For Loops and going throught a Matrix with just 2 For's.

Comment: Hello Ahmed AU. You are not completly wrong. It is true, but I have to take the X with the coresponding Y on the same row in the same table, which in the end might not give me the highest Shear. That is the reason why I have to check all combination possible. I could try a Preselection of some sort, but I will still have the Problem of For in For in For and with more that 15 tables I will still get I huge number of posible combination. I am trying to reduce the processing time by somehow getting rid of For in For in For loops and somehow manageing with only 2 For's or so. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you in Advance. Is just that I had run out of ideeas.If for 10 Billion combination the program runs for 5-10 min is okay but at the Moment is taking several minutes for around 200 000 which is a lot. Thank you a lot for you help.